# Logging using Microsoft account

Tags: wordpress, authentication, microsoft

I would like to create WordPress website with forum where people will be able to login with Microsoft account. I would like to do this to authorize their GamerTags from Xbox Live. Is that even possible?

Answer (score -1):

With the [Janrain plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rpx/), you can have users sign on with Microsoft accounts. Try it, and if you have any issues let us know.

**Edit:**
By us I mean the stack exchange community. I have played around with this plugin, so when I saw this question it popped into my head to see if Janrain supported Microsoft accounts.

I am going into ninth grade, and am not affiliated with Janrain.

Comment: Do you have an affiliation with this plugin?